# Distinct different for Delta Manager (Tomcat Session Replication)

Tags: session, tomcat, replication

Other than the fact that Delta Manager replicates to all Tomcat nodes (even on nodes that do not have the application hosted) and works better in smaller cluster and Backup Manager replicates to only another Tomcat node and works better in larger cluster, what is another distinct difference that makes Delta Manager really really different from Backup Manager?

I searched all over the net but could not find it :(

The network traffic? Or any other attributes?

Answer (score 1):

The number of nodes that data is replicated to (one vs. all) is the key difference between the two ClusterManager implementations.

Comment: thanks @markthomas. i understand that the number of nodes that data is replicated is different. but are there any distinct differences between both implementation?

Or rather, why is deltamanager called a delta?

Comment: It is just a name. They both work the same way apart from the number of nodes data is replicated to.